# cordovaHTTP.post body parameters not being sent

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

Trying to use cordovaHTTP.post method. It is hitting my server(node / express based) just fine, however, req.body is coming in empty. Here is the code I am using:

```
            let url = "http://192.168.51.77:8000/beacon/detected";
            let data = {
                someData: 'foobar'
            };
            let headers = {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            };
            cordovaHTTP.post(url, data, headers,
                function (response) {
                    // Create tag to display beacon data.
                    var element = $(
                        '<div>'
                        // + JSON.parse(response.headers)
                        + JSON.parse(response.data).data.content[0].body
                        + '</div>' 
                    );
                    $('#kne-response').html(element);
                },
                function (response) {
                    console.error(response.error);
                });
```

Comment: Did you found a solution? I have the same problem